# How to rename the root partition of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, home-directory, macosx, rename

I have a *Triple Boot setup* on my MacBook Pro (2015 Retina) with *MacOS Sierra, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04*. When I install Ubuntu to one of the partitions, it renames the partition to *Untitled*.

I tried to rename the partition using the disk utility (Mac), but although I am still able to boot into Ubuntu, an error message appears.

**Is there any way to rename this partition safely without losing data?**

Comment: Is that partition just your `/home` directory or your whole Ubuntu partition?

Comment: @Zanna it's the whole Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 2):

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**, once on the **Ubuntu Live desktop** open **GParted**. Right-click the partition you want to rename - select **Label File System** and enter a name for the partition. Click on **Apply** to finalize the pending operation.

This is the safest method to rename the partition - because  all gets done on an unmounted disk.
In the example shown below I renamed the Ubuntu root partition, when you created a separate `/home` partition during the installation process, the procedure to rename it is exactly the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this same as I renaming the same partition (on to which Ubuntu is installed) from macOS?

Comment: @abArackal : It is the safe way to rename a partition from within a live environment, where no systems are running. Basically the action is the same as what you tried to achieve and to do from the running MacOS. :)